# Couchbase php / .Net client incompatibility Issue

Tags: c#, php, memcached, couchbase

We are trying to use the couchbase clients for PHP and .NET.  We are getting an error when we set a value with C# then read it with PHP.  We don't have any issues going the other direction or reading the values when telneting to the server.  Does anyone know why we are getting an error?

The php 'get' call causes the following error:

Warning: Couchbase::get() [couchbase.get]: could not decompress value (bad content) in D:\inetpub\Webadvisor\its\test\couchbase.php on line 5

The error comes from couchbase.c in the php-ext-couchbase repository found on github.
https://github.com/couchbase/php-ext-couchbase/blob/master/convert.c#L213

C# Code: (this works fine)

```
Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientConfiguration config = new Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientConfiguration();
config.Urls.Add(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools"));
CouchbaseClient client = new CouchbaseClient(config);
client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "foo", "bar");
client.Dispose();
```

PHP Code:

```
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1", "", "", "default");
var_dump($cb->get("foo"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem with the .NET and PHP clients not being compatible comes down to what the client sets the memcache flag to. These flags are used to tell the client the type of the value stored. .NET bases its flags on the Type.GetTypeCode() method.  So for example when the .NET client writes a string to cache it sets the flag to 274 however PHP does not know anything about the .NET typing scheme and does not know what to do with the value so it tries to decompress the value and this throws an error.  When PHP writes a string to cache it sets the flag to 0.

We have found two different fixes for the issue.  The first one is more of a work around.  If you set the PHP Couchbase option COUCHBASE_OPT_IGNOREFLAGS to true it will start working.

```
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1", "", "", "default");
$cb->setOption(COUCHBASE_OPT_IGNOREFLAGS,true);
```

The second solution that we ended up going with was overloading the .NET Transcoder (Enyim.Caching.Memcached.ITranscoder) and setting the flags to match the PHP flags.

```
public class PHPTranscoder : ITranscoder
{
    ...
    public static uint TypeCodeToFlag(TypeCode code)
    {
        switch (code)
        {
            case TypeCode.String: return 0;
            case TypeCode.Int16: return 1;
            case TypeCode.Int32: return 1;
            case TypeCode.Int64: return 1;
            case TypeCode.UInt16: return 1;
            case TypeCode.UInt32: return 1;
            case TypeCode.UInt64: return 1;
            case TypeCode.Decimal: return 2;
            case TypeCode.Boolean: return 3;
            default: return 0; //default to string
        }

        // THE FOLLOWING IS COUCHBASE'S ORGINAL CODE
        // return (uint)((int)code | 0x0100);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because php extension is using `php` serializer by default to allow to seamlessly serialize broader kinds of objects in PHP. Here is the excerpt from example config, explaining available options: https://github.com/couchbase/php-ext-couchbase/blob/master/example/couchbase.ini#L44-L52

```
; Specify the serializer to use to store objects in the Couchbase cluster.
;
; Legal values:
;   php        - Use the standard php serializer
;   json       - Use the php JSON encoding
;   json_array - Same as json, but decodes into arrays
;   igbinary   - This option is only available if the extension is build
;                with igbinary support
couchbase.serializer = php
```

In your case I think you should use `json` serializer instead.